# Get user roles from within controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization

I built a custom authorization class that inherits from `AuthorizeAttribute`. It returns a list of `enum AccessLevel`, as users can have multiple roles. I decorated my controller methods, like the example below that restricts SomeFunction to only Admins and/or Approvers:

`[MyAuthorization(AccessLevels = new[] { AccessLevel.Admin, AccessLevel.Approver })]
public ActionResult SomeFunction()
{
    \\Do stuff...
}`

My question is - is there a way to get the user's access levels from within SomeFunction without having to go get them all over again? Or is the list of access levels lost after the controller checks them?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for:

```
User.IsInRole("role here")
```

Or

```
UserManager.FindByNameAsync("name").Roles
```

Comment: I did try the `User.IsInRole("Admin")` and even though I am, it always returns false. Is there something special you have to do for non-standard roles? Also, UserManager doesn't seem to exist: `The name 'UserManager' does not exist in the current context`.